# in EAP7, we have set jboss.server.data.dir repeatedly (various ways) and it seems to be set, but we are still getting this error:

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

in EAP7, we have set system variable jboss.server.data.dir repeatedly (various ways) and it seems to be set, but we are still getting this error:

```
16:54:06,015 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /stop
16:54:06,062 ERROR [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 98) Unable to initialize LoadCompanyIdsContext: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${jboss.server.data.dir}/etc/companyIds.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)......
```

(many more of these follow)  Even though, that XML file is there!

Comment: check `jboss.server.data.dir` if it is set properly or not.

Comment: How are you setting it? The best way would be in the `JAVA_OPTS` of the `standalone.conf` file.